# How can I set state of dynamic parameter using a Link To

Tags: reactjs

I have a table with a lot of items, each item has a link to show the item detail.
I'm listing the items, but I need to get the id of the item clicked to show their details.

That's my state:

```
  this.state = {                       

            dataTable: [
                idItem: '',                             
                list: {
                    headerListItems: [],
                    bodyItems: []
                }
            ]
        }
    this.itemDetail = this.itemDetail.bind(this)
```

I show the items and each item have a detail link with his id:

```
     ...    <td><Link to={ --should I pass any parameter here? -- }>            
                <span onClick={props.itemDetail}>Detail</span>
            </Link></td> ....
```

How can I call the `itemDetail` function and set the `idItem` of the respective item clicked?

That's my itemDetail

```
itemDetail(evento) {
        this.setState({
            dataTable: Object.assign(this.state.dataTable, {                
                list: [
                    {headerListItems: [...]},
                    {bodyItems: this.state.dataTable.list[1].body.filter(function (l) {                        
                        return l.idItem == idItem
                    })},
                ]
            }),
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you passed had errors in the state, in the function and in the render. Maybe it's better to start over.
I hope that this following code can be a starting point for what you are looking for:

```
class AbdoExample extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedItem: '',
            listItems: [{ link: '#item1' }, { link: '#item2' }, { link: '#item3' }]
        };
    }

    selectItem = (event, value) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ selectedItem: value });
    };

    render() {
        const { selectedItem, listItems } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <div>selectedItem: {selectedItem}</div>
                {listItems.map((item, index) => {
                    const linkKey = `${item.link}-${index}`;
                    return (
                        <button
                            key={linkKey}
                            type="button"
                            onClick={event => {
                                this.selectItem(event, item.link);
                            }}
                        >
                            {item.link}
                        </button>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I simplified my code here. That's why looks not so good. But I got some concepts that u expose and it works fine. But one more doubt, how can I do the same changing the button to Link To?

Comment: Try something like this:  <Link to={selectedItem} >

Answer (score 1):

> How can I call the `itemDetail` function and set the `idItem` of the respective item clicked?

To do it, you need to call the `itemDetail` function with the id as an argument and change its signature.

Assuming that you're rendering the items on a loop, just add the id as a parameter on the function call.

```
...
itemDetail(evento, id) {
  this.setState({
    dataTable: Object.assign(this.state.dataTable, {    
      idItem: id,
      list: [
    ...
    }
}
...
// assuming that you have a loop like for(item in this.state.dataTable.list)
<td>
  <Link to={this.state.idItem}>            
    <span onClick={(event) => props.itemDetail(event, item.id)}>Detail</span>
  </Link>
</td>
...
```

But the Link redirect shouldn't work, cause when you clicked on it, the link has the old value.

If you're rendering it in a loop, you can avoid it all, and set the link when rendering the item.

```
...
<td>
  <Link to={item.id}> //replace the id with your link key            
    <span onClick={props.itemDetail}>Detail</span>
  </Link>
</td>
...
```

Comment: tks for your help. I didn't choose your answer because the other one was more effective